# Bind a list of values from an array for a mysql prepare statement

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a PHP/MySQL set up with an associative array which I use to store values from a database, allow the user to manipulate those values and then commit any changes back to the database.

I can read and store the values in quite a neat way, but I hit a challenge when attempting to write back to the database.

```
$tags = array (
  array ( "tag" => "tag1", "name" => "Tag 1", "value" = > "0.1"),
  array ( "tag" => "tag2", "name" => "Tag 2", "value" = > "0.2"),
  array ( "tag" => "tag3", "name" => "Tag 3", "value" = > "0.3")
)
```

When I come to build the mysql insert statement, I'm successful write up until the bind_param statement.

```
$tagNames = implode(", ", array_column($tags, "tag"));
  // Creates a comma separated list of column names for the INSERT statement,
    e.g. "tag1, tag2, tag3"
$tagTypes = str_repeat('d', count($tags));
  // Creates a string of 'd's for the bind_param statement (I'm inserting floating point / doubles),
    e.g. "ddd" 
$tagParams = str_repeat('?,', count($tags) - 1) . '?';
  // Creates a comma separated string of '?'s for the VALUES part of the INSERT statement, ensuring the last parameter isn't followed by a comma,
    e.g. "?, ?, ?"
$tagValues = implode(", ", array_column($tags, "value"));
  // Creates a comma separated string containing the values,
    e.g. "0.1, 0.2, 0.3"
```

The INSERT statement looks like this:

```
$sql = $this->mysqli->prepare("
  INSERT INTO tableName (
    id, " . $tagNames . ")
  VALUES (?, " . $tagParams . ")");
$sql->bind_param('i' . $tagTypes, $this->gameId, $tagValues);
```

What I want the SQL statement to read is:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (
  id, tag1, tag2, tag3)
VALUES (1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3)
```

What the code is actually doing is generating a string containing the values, and therefore the number of values being passed into the prepare statement doesn't match the number of parameters:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (
  id, tag1, tag2, tag3)
VALUES (1, "0.2, 0.2, 0.3")
```

How do I get a list of values into the bind_param statement rather than a string containing the list of values?

I've explored `extract()` and am familiar with `array_column()`, but can't quite figure this one out!

Comment: Don't you realize that all this mess is for naught, because you are adding column names directly from the user input and thus making your SQL wide open to any injection?

Comment: Thanks - I didn't find that question/answer when searching. The unpacking operator is exactly what I needed: ```...array_column($tags, "value")``` works! As for the adding of column names dynamically, this function is not directly available to user input, so is less insecure. That wasn't clear from my question, as I didn't feel that this was relevant to the question.

Comment: I don't care for whatever "function". It is **column names** I am talking about which  directly, according to your own words, are coming to SQL: " the user to manipulate those values and then commit any changes back to the database"